# greatest integer function graph

Tags: calculus

I need a little help about graphing this greatest integer function

## [y-2]={x+1}

I know how to graph only the greatest integer function $y=[x]$ , but I have no idea how to sart my homework because I have on the left side also greatest integer of  $ y-2 $ and it's confusing me , I need just some steps how to start this . Thank you all for helping!

Comment: A little hint: the range of $\{\cdot\}$ is $[0,1)$

Comment: Plot some points until you see some patterns, then plot some more points until you are certain you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $[\,]$ is the greatest integer function and hence assumes only integer values whereas $\{\}$ is the fractional part function and assumes only fractional values and $0$ with its range $[0,1)$ as mentioned in the comment by  *user3313320*.

Since L.H.S. must be equal to R.H.S., the only values possible for $y$ $\in [2,3)$. Hence the domain of this function is $\mathbb{Z}$ and range of this function is $[2,3)$.

Comment: Surely the point $(5,2.17)$ lies on the curve, no?

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for the help. I have corrected my answer.